# How to test `catch` and `then` with sinon js?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocha.js, sinon, chai

I have been trying to stub and mock my function to be able to test my function

```
SetExample.createCandyBox = function(config) {
    this.getCandies(config.candyUrl)
    .catch(() => {
        return {};
    })
    .then((candies) => {
        Advertisements.pushCandyBox(config, candies);
    });
};
```

I want to test a scenario when the config.candyUrl is incorrect(404, etc) with something like:

```
it('should return to an empty array when url is incorrect', sinon.test(function() {
    // Fixture is an element I created for testing. 
    var configStub = SetExample.getCandyConfig(fixture);
    var createCandyBoxMock = sinon.mock(config);

    createCandyBoxMock.expects('catch');

    SetExample. createCandyBox(configStub);
}));
```

When I do this, term is error => Can't find variable: config.
What did I do wrong? can someone help and explain? I am new to Sinon :( Thx in advance!

Comment: The variable `config` is never defined in your test. Why do you expect it to be there and what value do you expect it to have?

Comment: ah sorry I replace `config` with `SetExample` and it worked with my simple test function `return "yay!"`. But then it still doesn't solve my test problem. All I want is to test when I put a wrong URL inside `createCandyBox` then it returns to `{}`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sinon.stub()` to stub `this.getCandies` and its resolved/rejected value. And stub `Advertisements.pushCandyBox`, then make an assertion to check if it has been called or not.

E.g.

`SetExample.js`:

```js
const Advertisements = require('./Advertisements');

function SetExample() {}

SetExample.getCandies = async function (url) {
  return 'your real getCandies implementation';
};

SetExample.createCandyBox = function (config) {
  return this.getCandies(config.candyUrl)
    .catch(() => {
      return {};
    })
    .then((candies) => {
      Advertisements.pushCandyBox(config, candies);
    });
};

module.exports = SetExample;
```

`Advertisements.js`:

```js
function Advertisements() {}

Advertisements.pushCandyBox = function (config, candies) {
  return 'your real pushCandyBox implementation';
};

module.exports = Advertisements;
```

`SetExample.test.js`

```
const SetExample = require('./SetExample');
const Advertisements = require('./Advertisements');
const sinon = require('sinon');

describe('38846337', () => {
  describe('#createCandyBox', () => {
    afterEach(() => {
      sinon.restore();
    });
    it('should handle error', async () => {
      const err = new Error('timeout');
      sinon.stub(SetExample, 'getCandies').withArgs('wrong url').rejects(err);
      sinon.stub(Advertisements, 'pushCandyBox');
      await SetExample.createCandyBox({ candyUrl: 'wrong url' });
      sinon.assert.calledWithExactly(SetExample.getCandies, 'wrong url');
      sinon.assert.calledWithExactly(Advertisements.pushCandyBox, { candyUrl: 'wrong url' }, {});
    });
  });
});
```

unit test result:

```
  38846337
    #createCandyBox
      ✓ should handle error


  1 passing (7ms)

-------------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File               | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
-------------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files          |   81.82 |      100 |   42.86 |   81.82 |                   
 Advertisements.js |   66.67 |      100 |       0 |   66.67 | 4                 
 SetExample.js     |    87.5 |      100 |      60 |    87.5 | 6                 
-------------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
```